# Objective-C: Asynchronously populate UITableView - how to do this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I can't seem to find any info on this question, so I thought I'd ask the community.

Basically, I have a UITableView and I want to show an activity indicator while its data is loading from my server.

Here is some example code of what I'm trying to do (I'm using ASIHttpRequest).

```
    //self.listData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Red", @"Green", @"Blue", @"Indigo", @"Violet", nil];   //this works
    NSString *urlStr=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com"];   //some slow request
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

    __block ASIHTTPRequest *request=[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setCompletionBlock:^{
        self.listData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Red", @"Green", @"Blue", @"Indigo", @"Violet", nil];   //this doesn't work...
        [table reloadData];

    }];
    [request setFailedBlock:^{

    }];
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

The dummy request to google.com does nothing - it just creates a delay and in the response I hope to repopulate the table with some JSON response from my own website.

But when I try to populate the table with the colours, nothing happens! I just get a blank table... If I uncomment the line above, it works fine, it's just on http responses things don't work for me.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

### Edit:

I did a `[self.tableView reloadData];` and now it works...

Answer (score 64, accepted):

1. Stop using ASIHTTPRequest.  `NSURLConnection` is not hard to use and will result in better, more performant code.
2. Your JSON response should be fed into a data structure not the UI.  I recommend Core Data.
3. The data structure should feed your `UITableView`.  Again, I recommend Core Data.

I would suggest reviewing how MVC works, you are short circuiting the design and that is the core problem.

## SPOILER

Here is a more detailed how to.  First you want the data retrieval to be async.  Easiest and most reusable way to do that is build a simple NSOperation subclass.

```
@class CIMGFSimpleDownloadOperation;

@protocol CIMGFSimpleDownloadDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)operation:(CIMGFSimpleDownloadOperation*)operation didCompleteWithData:(NSData*)data;
- (void)operation:(CIMGFSimpleDownloadOperation*)operation didFailWithError:(NSError*)error;

@end

@interface CIMGFSimpleDownloadOperation : NSOperation

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger statusCode;

- (id)initWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request andDelegate:(id<CIMGFSimpleDownloadDelegate>)delegate;

@end
```

This subclass is the most basic way to download something from a URL.  Construct it with a `NSURLRequest` and a delegate.  It will call back on a success or failure.  The implementation is only slightly longer.

```
#import "CIMGFSimpleDownloadOperation.h"

@interface CIMGFSimpleDownloadOperation()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURLRequest *request;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *data;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<CIMGFSimpleDownloadDelegate> delegate;

@end

@implementation CIMGFSimpleDownloadOperation

- (id)initWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request andDelegate:(id<CIMGFSimpleDownloadDelegate>)delegate
{
  if (!(self = [super init])) return nil;

  [self setDelegate:delegate];
  [self setRequest:request];

  return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
  [self setDelegate:nil];
  [self setRequest:nil];
  [self setData:nil];

  [super dealloc];
}

- (void)main
{
  [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[self request] delegate:self];
  CFRunLoopRun();
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse*)resp
{
  [self setStatusCode:[resp statusCode]];
  [self setData:[NSMutableData data]];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)newData
{
  [[self data] appendData:newData];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection
{
  [[self delegate] operation:self didCompleteWithData:[self data]];
  CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{
  [[self delegate] operation:self didFailWithError:error];
  CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
}

@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize request;
@synthesize data;
@synthesize statusCode;

@end
```

Now this class is VERY reusable.  There are other delegate methods for NSURLConnection that you can add depending on your needs. `NSURLConnection` can handle redirects, authentication, etc. I **strongly** suggest you look into its documentation.

From here you can either spin off the `CIMGFSimpleDownloadOperation` from your `UITableViewController` or from another part of your application.  For this demonstration we will do it in the `UITableViewController`.  Depending on your application needs you can kick off the data download wherever makes sense.  For this example we will kick it off when the view appears.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];

  NSURLRequest *request = ...;
  CIMGFSimpleDownloadOperation *op = [[CIMGFSimpleDownloadOperation alloc] initWithURLRequest:request andDelegate:self];
  [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:op];
  [self setDownloadOperation:op]; //Hold onto a reference in case we want to cancel it
  [op release], op = nil;
}
```

Now when the view appears an async call will go and download the content of the URL.  In this code that will either pass or fail.  The failure first:

```
- (void)operation:(CIMGFSimpleDownloadOperation*)operation didFailWithError:(NSError*)error;
{
  [self setDownloadOperation:nil];
  NSLog(@"Failure to download: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
}
```

On success we need to parse the data that came back.

```
- (void)operation:(CIMGFSimpleDownloadOperation*)operation didCompleteWithData:(NSData*)data;
{
  [self setDownloadOperation:nil];
  NSLog(@"Download complete");

  //1. Massage the data into whatever we want, Core Data, an array, whatever
  //2. Update the UITableViewDataSource with the new data

  //Note: We MIGHT be on a background thread here.
  if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
  } else {
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [[self tableView] reloadData];
    });
  }
}
```

And done.  A few more lines of code for you to write but it replaces 13K+ lines of code that gets imported with ASI resulting in a smaller, leaner, faster application.  And more importantly it is an app that you understand *every single line of code*.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. There are still some tasks that are great with asi (like downloading large files with resume-feature) but overall https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking is the future.

Comment: `NSURLConnection` is the future. Seriously, it is easy and covers every use case I have run across.  Never add a third party framework to your app unless you know exactly what it is doing.

Comment: A nice alternative to bare `NSURLConnection` is the excellent `PRPConnection` available as sample code from the even more excellent [iOS Recipes](http://pragprog.com/book/cdirec/ios-recipes) by Paul Warren and Matt Drance.  `PRPConnection` provides a pretty thin block based wrapper around `NSURLConnection` giving you methods like:

`+ (id)connectionWithURL:(NSURL *)requestURL
          progressBlock:(PRPConnectionProgressBlock)progress
        completionBlock:(PRPConnectionCompletionBlock)completion`

Comment: +1 to using PRPConnection as a wrapper for NSURLConnection with nice block callbacks.

Comment: @Marcus S. Zarra - many thanks for the pointers. I'm probably going to stop using ASIHttpRequest. It would be really great if you could post some code snippets of the kind of stuff you're talking about? Many thanks,

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra While I absolutely agree with you, it's really up to the developer to decide how much control he wants over his code. Personally, I would never bother trying to parse something like JSON myself when I can rely on a third-party framework like JSONKit. The same goes for networking, honestly. Of course, I'm aware of the risks of relying on those libraries.

Comment: Telling him to stop using ASI as your first suggestion is really not helping.  ASI is a great library.  Should you use it 100% of the time?  Perhaps not, but 99% probably.  In any case, his question is related to updating the UI from a background thread, which is obviously the cause of the issue.  Core Data?!?!?  NOT PART OF THE QUESTION AT ALL.  While a gentle nudge to not consume raw API responses directly in a view controller is a good idea, blindly telling him to make drastic architectural changes is definitely not helping.

Comment: Totally agree with Ben. There's this weird ASI-hate happening on Twitter these days, and frankly I don't understand the reason. ASI is a great convenience toolkit for those day to day HTTP interactions.

Comment: ASI is 13K lines of code to replace developer effort of **maybe** 100 lines of code or 200 lines of code.  It is accepting a *huge* black box so that the developer can save 100 lines of code.  ASI is laziness and bloat. There is a reason why people don't like it. It is an unnecessary crutch; a poor reimplementation because the author most likely did not understand `NSURLConnection` to begin with and feared what he did not understand.

Comment: I agree, ASI is way too heavy for most projects. Saying that you should use it in 99% of instances is insane. If you really don't want to use NSURLConnection, look into a smaller library like Seriously or the aforementioned PRPConnection for block-based connection API. I'll put money on the fact that 9/10 projects that use ASI don't use any of the advanced features of ASI, and would be much better off with a smaller library.

Comment: I want to ask why you suggesting not to use NSMutableArray for data storage and suggesting core data ? I have array and data doesn't need to be persistent.

Comment: @kesrut In general your data should be decoupled from your UI. Core Data is designed exactly for that purpose. If you have something truly simple then a `NSArray` is fine. If you are grabbing data from a network then it is probably not simple, probably should be cached and probably should not be in a `NSArray`.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra I like this alot and am still learning, how hard would it be to change it to a block version?

Comment: Probably not very difficult.  You give up some control when you use the block implementations from `NSURLConnection` so I tend to stay away from them myself.

Comment: The best answer I have ever seen. Period.

Answer (score 12):

This is the problem

```
request setCompletionBlock:^{
        self.listData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Red", @"Green", @"Blue", @"Indigo", @"Violet", nil];   //this doesn't work...
        [table performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadTable) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];    
    }];
```

The reload table needs to be done on the main thread.

Comment: reloadTable will change the UI, all UI interaction must be done on the main thread.

Comment: Hey, I tried your code, but it doesn't seem to work... I'm really stuck now and don't know what to do!

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in the method call.

Comment: so how can we reload table on the main thread? @NWCoder ,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried NWCoder's solution, and it didn't work because its calling the wrong method. This is what i used.
`[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];`