# How to prevent multiple clicks generating multiple NSOperations

Tags: objective-c, nsoperation

I used [Marcus Zarra's excellent advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491517/objective-c-asynchronously-populate-uitableview-how-to-do-this/7492587#7492587) on how to do async downloads using NSURLConnection and NSOperation. I have tied a button press to that NSOperationg.

Question is: how do I prevent the user from spamming the button and shooting off many NSOperations doing the same download over and over again.

I have two concerns:

a) Setting a global variable is probably not a good idea. What happens if the app is suspended with the flag on?

b) Disabling the button upon the first click is probably a bad idea too. If something goes wrong with my code, the button might stay disabled.

I don't really understand what happens if the app is suspened mid-operation, but mostly I'd like to know the "philosophy" of going about this.

I think most ios apps that consume webservices have this exact same problem, but I don't know what's best practice.

Thank you. I looked and this doesn't seem to be a dupe. If it is, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to show a "loading view" which will cover all of the buttons and give information to the user that something is happening. This has the same problems as disabling the button though: you need to make sure you remove it on completion of the operation, or replace it with an appropriate message if something goes wrong