# NSURLConnection delegates not invoked in NSOperation

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsurlconnection, nsoperation

I need to add upload functionality and all is done except the progress indicator. I am using an `NSOperation` to initiate the HTTP request, so uploads would happen in background. But by doing so `NSURLConnection` delegates are not getting invoked.

```
//.h file
@interface FooNSOperation : NSOperation<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
...
@end
// .m file
@implementation FooNSOperation
...
- (void) main {
  // Upload using NSURLRequest, NSURLConnection
  // NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: queue: completionHandler:
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite {
  // This never gets invoked
}
@end
```

How can I get upload progress ?

Comment: Why are you using NSOperation? `sendAsynchronousRequest:` already works in the background

Comment: In addition if you use `NSURLConnectionsendAsynchronousRequest: queue: completionHandler:` delegate has not been set up and so not called anywhere.

Comment: @HaniIbrahim It does not work in the background but in a async fashion. With `NSURLConnectionsendAsynchronousRequest: queue: completionHandler:delegate` you can choose the queue to work with and hence a different queue from the main one.

Comment: @HaniIbrahim It can be multiple file uploads, and I need pause and resume functionality so I thought of using NSOperations and queue so that I can suspend and resume.

Comment: So, to not reinvent the wheel just use **AFNetworking**.

Comment: @flexaddicted I already came across that answer but that link didnt work for me. If its working for you could you post a gist of that link in the answer itself ?

Comment: you can use `NSURLSession` iOS 7

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491517/objective-c-asynchronously-populate-uitableview-how-to-do-this

Comment: @HaniIbrahim There are lots of reasons to use `NSOperation` rendition with `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods. Primarily, you can make make your operations cancelable and handle progress updates (e.g. to update determinate progress indicator view). Furthermore, if you have to do any authentication, redirect handling, streaming, etc., you really need those delegate calls, too. You can also use operation dependencies, too. `NSOperation`-based requests offers tons of advantages.

Comment: @flexaddicted yes this is what I meant (Async)

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the info I'll need to try that soon :)